# Want to add New Bean in jhipster

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jhipster

i am working on fileupload(Jquery file upload).i want to add a new bean for accept multiple request i.e

```
<bean
     class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" id="multipartResolver">     
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
```

if we using simple Spring mvc application then we hae to add in Servet-context.xml file.
but in jhipster i am unable to find any .xml so please help me where we have to enter this bean for file upload.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JHipster we are not using the Spring XML configuration (it would work, it's a design choice), we are using Java Config instead.
Have a look at the [Java Config documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) to see how you can configure a bean in Java. It's not very different from your XML configuration, just a different syntax.

Comment: I have create a new bean but while running project getting exception:                                                      Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration.setBeanFactory(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory;)V